# I Cant enable the Responsive-Navigation module after installing it

Tags: navigation

I want to make the Nav menu responsive for my website and I just downloaded the files for Responsive-Navigation and responsive-nav.js plugin and copied them in modules and libraries folders respectively. The problem is I can't enable the Responsive Navigation module. Help

Comment: What does it mean you can't enable it exactly? Any error message? How you know you can't enable it? Only from the UI? And Drush or Drupal Console?

Comment: From the UI, Admin/modules: When I try to enable Gmap for example, it refreshes the page, and remains disabled.